# How to fill a ScrollBox from ListView items

Tags: delphi, vcl

I have a ListView with a number of fields inside of it.

On the other side, I have a ScrollBox that I want to fill in with data from the ListView.

This is done by creating a dynamic panel that contains a set of Labels to represent the data on the panel.

[image]

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  PngImageList, Vcl.Menus,
  Vcl.ComCtrls, siComp, Registry, System.ImageList, Vcl.ImgList,
  Vcl.Imaging.pngimage, rkGlassButton;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
    LV: TListView;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;
  Pnl : TPanel;
 LabName : TLabel;
 LabId : TLabel;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 posX,posY : SmallInt;

  I: Byte;
  Item: TListItem;

begin

   posX := 0;
   posY := 0;
   for I := 0 to LV.Items.Count -1 do
    begin
      Pnl := TPanel.Create(ScrollBox1);
      Pnl.Parent           := ScrollBox1;
      Pnl.Left             := posX  -1;
      Pnl.Top              := posY  -1;
      Pnl.Width            := ScrollBox1.Width;
      Pnl.Height           := 40;
      Pnl.BorderStyle      := bsNone;
      Pnl.BevelInner       := bvNone;
      Pnl.BevelKind        := bkNone;
      Pnl.BevelOuter       := bvNone;
      Pnl.ParentBackground := false;
      Pnl.Color            := clWhite;
      Pnl.Anchors          := [akTop, akRight,akLeft];
      posY := posY + Pnl.Height;
     //-------------------
        LabName := TLabel.Create(Pnl);
        LabName.Parent := Pnl;
        LabName.Top := 10;
        LabName.Left := 40;;
        LabName.Font.Size := 11;
        LabName.Caption :=LV.Items; // ??? ListView  (RN)
    //--------------------
        LabId := TLabel.Create(Pnl);
        LabId.Parent := Pnl;
        LabId.Top := 10;
        LabId.Left := 100;;
        LabId.Font.Size := 11;
        Item := LV.Items;
        LabId.Caption := LV.Items;; // ???  ListView  (RC)
    end;
end;

end.
```

The panel is well constructed, but I do not know how to set the label captions using items in the ListView.

Please help me to correct my code.

Comment: General hint: Don't forget to set `ReadOnly` to `True` if you don't want to be able to edit the captions and `ColumnClick` to `False` if you don't want to implement column-click-based sorting. Personally, I fancy setting `RowSelect` to `True` as well.

Comment: Also, a hint for future Stack Overflow questions. Notice that your problem really has *nothing* to do with scroll boxes. Instead, it is about how to access the various cells (columns) in a list view row. You should have asked about that specifically. No need even to mention the scroll box.

Comment: Finally, `Pnl`, `LabName`, and `LabId` *really* should be local variables, and `I` should be a true `Integer`. Also no need to  make `posX` and `posY` `SmallInt`. Use `Integer`.

Comment: And don't forget to enable thumb tracking in the scroll box: Set `VertScrollBar.Tracking` to `True` (and similarly for the horisontal scroll bar). Otherwise it is back to the 80s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for `LV.Items[i].Caption` and `LV.Items[i].SubItems[j]`.

- `Caption` is the text in the left-most cell.
- `SubItems[0]`, `SubItems[1]`, ..., `SubItems[LV.Columns.Count - 2]` yield the texts in the remaining cells.

So, in your case, given row `i`,

- `LV.Items[i].Caption` is the value in the "RN" column.
- `LV.Items[i].SubItems[0]` is the value in the "RC" column.
- `LV.Items[i].SubItems[1]` is the value in the "RFD" column.
- `LV.Items[i].SubItems[2]` is the value in the "RUR" column.
- `LV.Items[i].SubItems[3]` is the value in the "RID" column.
- `LV.Items[i].SubItems[4]` is the value in the "isV" column.